# "Expected in: flat namespace" error when importing networkx in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

I'm getting a strange error which I can't make sense of.

On Python 2.7, I installed the py27-networkx package using MacPorts. When I try to `import networkx as nx`, I get the error below. The only line in my `network.py` file is the import one.

Any ideas on how to debug this to work out what's happening?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "network.py", line 1, in <module>
    import networkx
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from networkx import release
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx/release.py", line 45, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 427, in <module>
    import select
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/select.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyInt_AsInt
  Referenced from: /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/select.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/select.so
```

**Update**

Ran a few pieces to help diagnose. Hope it helps someone provide some insight and a solution to this for me.

- `which python` gives me `/opt/local/bin/python` (I have the standard Mac OS X python, but am using a MacPorts installed version of python2.7)
- Running `import networkx` from the python prompt produces no errors
- Anything else I can try?

Answer (score -1):

I also had this error and i fixed by upgrading `python27` with `macports`.

Update macports to the latest version:

```
sudo port selfupdate
```

List outdated packages (python27 was outdated for me, when I was getting the import error):

```
sudo port outdated
```

Update the outdated packages:

```
sudo port upgrade outdated
```